# How to achieve that every record in two tables have different id?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have two tables  inherited from base table ( SQLALCHEMY models)

```
class Base(object):
    def __tablename__(self):
        return self.__name__.lower()

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    utc_time = Column(Integer, default=utc_time(), onupdate=utc_time())
    datetime = Column(TIMESTAMP, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.current_timestamp())
```

and inherited tables `Person` and `Data`
How to achieve that every Person and Data have different id, every id to be unique for two tables ? ( Person when generate of id to be aware of Data ids and vice versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using Postgresql, Firebird, or Oracle, use a sequence that's independent of both tables to generate primary key values.  Otherwise, you need to roll some manual process like an "id" table or something like that - this can be tricky to do atomically.

Basically if I were given this problem, I'd ask why exactly would two tables need unique primary key values like that - if the primary key is an autoincrementing integer, that indicates it's meaningless.  It's only purpose is to provide a unique key into a single table.